# SSRS Bar Chart 'Group1' is out of scope. It works in a report. Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report with a single group that is performing as I would expect.  The report definition looks like this:  (Sorry - I'm new here and don't have enough points to post an actual image.)

http://1drv.ms/1nQGIJU

The expression in the selected box says:

`=((Sum(Fields!AgentTalk.Value) + Sum(AgentAcdLoggedIn.Value)) / 3600 / (Lookup(ReportItems!Group1.Value, Fields!Sector.Value, Fields!ExpectedHours.Value, "BlockSchedule") * Parameters!BusinessDays.Value`)

This report runs fine and displays exactly what I need.

The problem, however, is that I am trying to do a bar chart representing the same thing and I am getting an error message indicating that "The Y expression for the chart 'Chart4' refers to the report item 'Group1'.  Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope. ..."

My chart definition looks like this:

http://1drv.ms/1o627dN

The expression I am using for the values is identical to the expression calculated in the report.  I have made sure that the name of the series group is 'Group1'.

This is all being done in Report Builder 3.0.  I have not been able to figure out how I can use the value of the series group in the lookup function so I can properly calculate what I am trying to display.

Comment: Is the chart placed inside the group?

Comment: I guess I'm not following that question.

The Series Group is defined for the chart.  It is named 'Group1'.  The aggregate values to be plotted are trying to reference the value of that group for the calculation.  (See the diagram I provided for the chart.)